# What does " _ = c(ctx, cmd)" mean?

Tags: go

I'm reading the code that go-redis library, and then I want to know how the  `_ = c(ctx, cmd)` works.

```
// Get Redis `GET key` command. It returns redis.Nil error when key does not exist.
func (c cmdable) Get(ctx context.Context, key string) *StringCmd {
    cmd := NewStringCmd(ctx, "get", key)
    _ = c(ctx, cmd)
    return cmd
}
```

I found type alias below but I couldn't find this function's body.

`type cmdable func(ctx context.Context, cmd Cmder) error`

why and how  `_ = c(ctx, cmd)` works without function body?

https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/master/commands.go#L780

Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe a little more about what is confusing to you?

Answer (score 5):

`cmdable` is defined as `type cmdable func(ctx context.Context, cmd Cmder) error`. So because it is an alias of a function it can call itself from a method. This works just like any other function variable:

```golang
abc := func(ctx context.Context, cmd Cmder) error {
    fmt.Println("we can do anything here")
    return nil
}

cmd := cmdable(abc)
```

So the actual function body is provided outside of this struct. They use it in a few places for example, this is the definition of [`Client`](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/v8.11.4/redis.go#L538):

```golang
type Client struct {
    *baseClient
    cmdable
    hooks
    ctx context.Context
}
```

It embeds `cmdable` so all exported methods on `cmdable` will become exported methods on `Client` as well. During creating of the `Client` in `NewClient` the cmdable is set to `c.Process`:

```golang
func NewClient(opt *Options) *Client {
    opt.init()

    c := Client{
        baseClient: newBaseClient(opt, newConnPool(opt)),
        ctx:        context.Background(),
    }
    c.cmdable = c.Process

    return &c
}
```

So in the case of `Client`, [`Client.Process`](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/v8.11.4/redis.go#L595) is the body of `c`. But for [`Pipeline`](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/master/pipeline.go#L40), [`Pipeline.Process`](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/master/pipeline.go#L73) is set. They do this because you want to queue commands before committing the pipeline.

So this is sort of a combination of inheritance from an abstract struct and a strategy pattern.

---

The `_ =` discards the return value which is an `error`. Using an underscore like this is called a [blank identifier](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier). This is not strictly necessary but is likely done to indicate to tools like [go vet](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/vet) that this is on purpose and that the author didn't forget to check an error.

Comment: sorry, I was unclear. I cant find this function body, so I want to know how it works. if it works as error checking, why it works without body? it is confusing me!

Comment: @ty I updated my answer to focus more one the function body, I hope this is a better explanation

Comment: I got it! It was really easy to understand. it's call as strategy pattern, so I'm looking it up.Thank you very much!